# Month name from date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone please suggest the shortest query in SQL Server to obtain the month name from a date?

I have tried this query

```
select 
    datename(month, dateadd(month, @mydate - 1, cast('2008-01-01' as datetime)))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this...

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, getdate()) AS [Month Name]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select CONVERT(varchar(3), getdate(), 100)  as Month
```

or

```
select FORMAT(getdate(), 'MMMM')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, GETDATE()) AS 'Month Name'
```

Answer (score 0):

### Do like this:

SELECT FORMAT(getdate(),'MMMM') AS [Month Name]